# Append data file to CSV file and output to another CSV file

Tags: python, csv, tabs, append

This may have been cover, apologies if it has. I could not find the exact answer under search. What I have is basically 3 files. The first one is a text file of main phrase, the second file is a csv file with approximately 1600 lines and 3 rows (city, state and zip) the third file is a text file with secondary phrase.

What I want to do is take file one (which will only have one phrase, eg; reputation management) and append it at the beginning of "each" line in the csv file, then remove the commas/tabs from the csv file and then append the thrid text file to the end of the line (the third text file will also only have one phrase, eg; online reputation companies) and then take the second column of the csv which would be the state and append it to the very end of the line.

An example output that I'm wanting to achieve would look like this:

Reputation Management Phoenix Arizona 87443 - Find Online Reputation Companies In Arizona

Reputation Management Tuscon Arizona 87444 - Contact Online Reputation Companies In Arizona

Reputation Management Albert Arizona 87445 - Find Online Reputation Companies In Arizona

Here is the code I have so far but I am stuck. It's not removing the tabs and it's only appending the first text file to line one in the output csv and not the other 1599 lines. Also when it gets to the type(secondarykeywordlist) I get a object of type '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len()

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
file = open('wordpress_input_file.csv', 'w')
file.write('' + type(mainkeywordlist).title().strip() + ' ' + ''.join(open('data_files/cities/arizona_cities.csv', 'r').readlines()).strip(",\n") + ' - ' + type(concat2).title().strip() + ' ' + type(secondarykeywordlist).title().strip() + '')
file.close()
```

Here is what my output looks like right now if I take out the secondarykeywordlist, I get an error putting it back in.

Reputation Management Phoenix Arizona 87443, Find

Edit:
I am running Python on Windows 7. Here is what the contents of the 3 files look like.

File 1 text file (Only 1 line): reputation management

File 2 csv file (1600 lines and 3 rows):

> > > phoenix,arizona,87443
> > >
> > > phoenix,tuscon,87444
> > >
> > > phoenix,albert,87445
> > >
> > > etc

File 3 text file (Only 1 line): online reputation companies

---

**SOLUTION FOUND FOR PROBLEM: Here is the working code that is working great now. Thank you all for your contribution.**

```
f_in = open("data_files/main_keyword.txt",'r')
prefix = f_in.read().strip()

f_in = open("data_files/secondary_keyword.txt", "r")
postfix = "%s\n" % (f_in.read().strip())

f_in = open('data_files/cities/texas_cities.csv', 'r')
f_out = open('wordpress_input_file.csv', 'w')
for line in f_in.readlines():
    f_out.write(prefix.title() + ' ' + line.strip().replace(","," ") + ' - ' +      type(concat2).title().strip() + ' ' + postfix.title().strip() + ' In ' + line.split(",")[1]+"\n" + '')
f_in.close()
f_out.close()
```

Comment: It would be useful if you said whether you are on Windows or Linux or Mac. Also if you showed 2-3 lines of each of your three files and what output would result. Also, if there are constraints on programming language and/or tools that can be used...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just open the first and third files, grab expressions from them under prefix and suffix variables respectively, then open the second file (with 1600 lines) and write processed output to the fourth file (out.txt - which will contain results you want). 
The code (after you grabbed prefix and suffix) would be:

```
f_in = open('file2.txt', 'r')
f_out = open('out.txt', 'w')
for line in f_in.readlines():
    f_out.write(prefix + ' ' + line.strip().replace(","," ") + \
    " " + suffix + " " +         line.split(",")[1]+"\n")
f_in.close()
f_out.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to process **each line**:

Something like:

```
with open("File1",'r') as f:
    prefix = f.read().strip()

with open("File", "r") as f:
    postfix = "%s\n" % (f.read().strip())

with open("csvfile", "r") as f:
   with open("outfile", "w") as g:
       for line in f.read():
           txt =line.strip().replace(',',' ')
           g.write( ' '.join([prefix, txt, postfix])
```

Comment: I ran this code and at the first = I get a syntax error (with f =)

Comment: Sorry - still getting used to the new `with` syntax - I've updated above.